# Angular 2 Http request error json parse

Tags: json, http, angular, httprequest, rxjs

I create a service called httpproviders

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Request,RequestMethod, Headers} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
//import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class Httpprovider {
    cities: Response;
    http: Http;
    constructor(http: Http){
        this.http = http;
    }
    httpReq(url: string, method: string, data: any, header: Headers){
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        //console.log(headers);

        if (method === 'GET'){ var methods = RequestMethod.Get} 
        else if (method === 'POST'){ var methods = RequestMethod.Post}
        else if (method === 'PUT'){var methods = RequestMethod.Put}
        else if (method === 'PATCH'){var methods = RequestMethod.Patch} 
        else if (method === 'DELETE'){var methods = RequestMethod.Delete}
        else {methods = RequestMethod.Get};

        return this.http.request(new Request({      <<<<<<
                    method: methods,                <<<<<<
                    url: url,                       <<<<<<
                    body: JSON.stringify(data),     <<<<<<
                    headers: headers                <<<<<<
                })).map(res => res.json());
    }

}
```

but my return request always keeps saying that my parameter did not match,
when I do a post request it's doing fine,  but when I do get request it sends error like this:

```
EXCEPTION: Unexpected end of JSON input

at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Response.Body.json (:3000/node_modules/@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js:768)
    at MapSubscriber.eval [as project] (:3000/app/service/httpprovider.js:47)
    at MapSubscriber._next (:3000/node_modules/rxjs/operator/map.js:77)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (:3000/node_modules/rxjs/Subscriber.js:89)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (:3000/node_modules/@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js:1168)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:275)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:4401)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:274)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:151)
    at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:345)
```

and my package json

```
"@angular/http": "~2.4.0",
"rxjs": "5.0.1",
```

this is in my component when I'm requesting the get http

> ```
> public concept: any[] = [];
> constructor( 
>     private _router: Router,
>     private _httpprovider: Httpprovider) { 
>
>     }
> ngOnInit(){
>     this.getconcept();
> }
> getconcept(){
>     this._httpprovider.httpReq('http://localhost:5000/getconcept','GET',null,null).subscribe((data)=>{
>         for (let i=0;i<data.length;i++){
>         this.concept.push(data[i]);
>         }
>     });
> };
> ```

Any idea what could be wrong?

Here is what I got from requesting get from server

```
[{"cbncept_desc":"AKkery"},{"cbncept_desc":"CBFDee & Other Bevereges"},{"cbncept_desc":"Dessert"},{"cbncept_desc":"Fast Food"},{"cbncept_desc":"Food CBurt"},{"cbncept_desc":"Restaurant"}]
```

Comment: Show server response that you get when doing GET request.

Comment: @SergeySokolov here i update  the question with the request get from server plese have a look

Comment: Hey Rommy can you print the value of `methods` after the last `else`?

Comment: @Rommy, Did you get it from browser's dev tools?

Comment: @SergeySokolov yeah i go to localhost:5000/getconcept and get an return like that

Comment: @btinoco sorry how can i print the value of the last methods ?

Comment: do a `console.log(methods)`  before the first if statement.

Comment: Does `.subscribe((data)=>{ console.log(data);..` print the same thing with the response json?

Comment: @echonax no it does not show anything

Comment: @btinoco i try it with console.log(methods) it show undefined

Comment: So you have an `undefined` request object because you didn't initialize `methods` like `var methods = '';` and you have an `undefined` response and you are wondering why this is not working?

Comment: @echonax well for POST request have the same result but its working fine, but get error , i guess its have some issue with Vaadin combo box, basically i want to insert data i get from mssql npm to vaadin combo box, but its showing error, if i insert it to table its working fine

Comment: @Rommy declare *methods* after  *headers*. ... do `let methods = RequestMethod.Get`  and remove the *var* from each if statement.   You can also remove the *first* and *last* if statements since you are declaring methods as RequestMethod.Get now.